# React make table clickable and edit details

Tags: reactjs

How do I make a table row clickable to edit and update details? I'm retrieving these details from pouchdb.

I'm pasting portion of my code below for your evaluation:

```
this.state = {docs: []}
this.db = this.props.db

componentDidMount () {
    this.updateDocs()
    this.db.changes({
      since: 'now',
      live: true
    }).on('change', (change) => {
      this.updateDocs()
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
  }

  updateDocs () {
    this.db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then((res) => {
      var docs = res.rows.map((row) => row.doc)
      this.setState({docs})
    })
  }
```

And the table below:

```
<div className='table-list'>
     <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Registration Type</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Middle Name</th>
       </tr>
       </thead>

       <tbody>
         {this.state.docs.map((doc) => <DataRow key={doc._id} doc={doc} {...this.props} />)}
       </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>

class DataRow extends React.Component {
  render () {
    let {doc} = this.props

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{doc.RegistrationInfo['registrationtype']}</td>
        <td>{doc.RegistrationInfo['firstname']}</td>
        <td>{doc.RegistrationInfo['middlename']}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to be able to click and edit each of the rows.

Comment: How do you plan on saving changes to each row after editing? In any case, one solution could be adding an `onClick` to the `tr` in `DataRow` and then settings its children (the `td` elements) editable using [¨HTMLElement.contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable)

Answer (score 3):

My first suggestion - do not do this. Editable grids are quite tough components to implement on your own.

Therefore you have some options to choose from:

1. Use existing frameworks with editable grids: [KendoUI](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui), [Wijmo](http://wijmo.com/products/wijmo-5/), etc. Although they are quite pricely and most of them have quite pure support for react as for now.
2. There are some standalone grids with editing functionality: [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/), [react data grid](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/all-features) etc. Some of them are free, other paid.
3. You can develop your own editable grid based on powerfull components like [fixed-data-table](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table), [react-virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List), etc. This approach will still will require some coding to be done but will save you a lot of time.
4. Make your own components as you are trying now.

If you still would like to go with #4 you can do it this way:

4.1. In state store column of the currently edited cell: `editingColumn`.

4.2. Assign onClick handler on your `<td>` tags: `<td onClick={(ev) => this.onCellClick(ev))}>`. In the handler set `editingColumn`

4.3. In your render replace

`<td>{doc.RegistrationInfo['registrationtype']}</td>`

with

`<td>{this.renderCell('columnName')}</td>`.

And `renderCell` will look something like this:

```
private renderCell(colName)
{
    if(this.state.editingColumn >= 0 && this.state.editingRow >= 0)
    {
         // Render your editing control here
         // Assign to its 'onChange' like event and save changes to this.props.RegistrationInfo[colName];
    }
    else
    {
         return this.props.RegistrationInfo[colName];
    }
}
```

This is very rough description but I hope it will help you get on going.