# React Virtualized Editable Rows

Tags: reactjs, material-design, textfield, react-virtualized

I am creating language flashcard software that relies on large lists of data. Some lists are editable (user created) and some are not (stock).

I need to have TextField Components in each TableCell. I am looking at the source code and it doesn't appear directly obvious.

Any recommendations?

https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304882/react-make-table-clickable-and-edit-details

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it looks like in the comment they recommend using another library then rolling your own editable. I wouldn't have an issue making my own or tweaking a more standard thing. I was wondering if specifically if there was a "virtualized" editable table of this nature or if someone had done it with the existing library. I haven't looked much since last time but afaik it is the same.